# SQL Join Tables with no common field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am looking to join two unrelated tables into a single table so i can sort by a common field and limit the combined resultset to display on the page.

Example

```
Table 1
Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | date_posted
--------------------------------------
Blah   | Blah2  | Blah3  | 2013-02-01 


Table 2
Field4 | Field 5 | date_posted
------------------------------
Blah4  | Blah5   | 2013-01-01 


Result
Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | Field5 | date_posted
--------------------------------------------------------
Blah   | Blah2  | Blah3  | NULL   | NULL   | 2013-02-01
NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | Blah4  | Blah5  | 2013-01-01
```

The reason for this is I have previously setup a database to display these tables on separate pages and now the client wants to combine them into a single page. If i run the queries separately and then combine the data in php there are certain issues such as pagination as well as having to select a set amount of each even if they are not the latest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No join necessary:

```
select field1, field2, field3, null as field4, null as field5, date_posted
from table_1
union all
select null,   null,   null,   field4,         field5,         date_posted
from table_2
```

To sort by a specific column, just add an `order by`

```
select field1, field2, field3, null as field4, null as field5, date_posted
from table_1
union all
select null,   null,   null,   field4,         field5,         date_posted
from table_2
order by date_posted
```

Note that in a UNION the order by always works on the full result, not on the individual parts. So even if it's placed right after the second select, it will sort everything.

To implement paging using `LIMIT`

Comment: @ArthurFrankel: which order by should be used? I can't see any reference in the question that the result should be ordered by a specific column (although it probably makes sense to order by the date column)

Comment: From his question "so i can sort by a common field and limit the combined resultset to display on the page" I was assuming the date_posted was the common field since it is common across the tables.

Comment: In the words of doctor who, "Fantastic!". I knew it had something to do with union all but couldn't get past the error about the tables not having the same number of fields. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, date_posted
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Field4, Field5, date_posted
FROM Table2
ORDER BY date_posted LIMIT 20
```

Comment: That will not work. The two parts of the UNION have different number of columns. And hireSwish wanted to have 6 columns, not 3 or 4.

Comment: Yes, my bad...you need nulls like you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select field1, field2, field3, null field4, null field5, date_posted from table1
union all
select null field1, null field2, null field3, field4, field5, date_posted from table2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69a46/1